# Python 3.9: Is read only Dictionary thread-safe

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

Env: Python 3.9 on RasPi OS: I am looking for a easier alternative to queueing for a threaded app. The dictionary structure (including all keys) will be initialized by main. A MQTT thread, with the dictionary as a global, would be responsible for writing the values as they arrive.  The main thread would only consume these values, never change them.  Is this scenario thread-safe?  With the GIL it would seem to be and this is a much simpler solution than queueing but I don’t want to have to use locks if I don’t have to.

Thanks.

Comment: If the data is modified by one thread only, what problems would you expect?

Comment: I expect none, hence the design.  Having many years writing multi-tasked/threaded programs the pervosity of systems frequently amaze me.

Comment: I read the answers you referenced as being a duplicate - it does not answer the question that I asked.  My question specifically referenced one thread only updating and another thread only reading.  I'll add locks but I believe they are unnecessary.